# Validação em Dropdownlist em ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou com problemas para validar o meu dropdown em uma view. No meu modelo utilizo um annotation Required como mostra o código abaixo:

Model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Informe uma cidade")]
[Display(Name="Cidade")]
public int CidadeID { get; set; }
```

View

```
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CidadeID, "CidadeID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("CidadeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CidadeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
```

Porém a validação não é realizada para o dropdown. Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Como você está povoando este DropDownList?

Comment: var itens = db.Cidades.ToList();
Cidade itemCidade = new Cidade();           
itens.Insert(0, itemCidade);ViewBag.CidadeID = new SelectList(itens, "CidadeID", "NomeCidade");

Comment: O dropdown está dentro de um form? Quando você gera o dropdown, o primeiro valor que aparece nele tem um value vazio?

Comment: A pergunta ainda está em aberto porque respostas não solucionaram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente o @required nos atributos de classe.

```
@Html.DropDownList("CidadeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @required = "required", @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você colocar um `OptionLabel` no seu `DropDownList` ele irá funcionar (no caso, o **"Selecione"** no exemplo abaixo).

Pode seguir esse exemplo:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <strong>@Html.LabelFor(e => e.CidadeId):</strong>
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.CidadeId, ViewBag.Cidades as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Selecione")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.CidadeId)
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
}
```

**Implementação da ViewBag**

```
ViewBag.Cidades = new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Cidade 1", Value="1"},
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Cidade 2", Value="2"},
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Cidade 3", Value="3"},
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Cidade 4", Value="4"},
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Cidade 5", Value="5"}
};
```

Daí é só você adaptar pra sua realidade.

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

**Apenas para exemplificar como exibir a mensagem**, fiz esses dois exemplos com base no seu código, onde ao clicar no botão e fazer o *Post* sem selecionar uma opção, a tela exibe a mensagem de erro:

**Exemplo com ViewBag:**

Model:

```
public class SeuModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe uma cidade")]
    [Display(Name = "Cidade")]
    public int CidadeID { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
        public ActionResult DropDown()
        {
            var model = new SeuModel();

            ViewBag.Cidades = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Selecione", Value="", Selected = true},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Cidade 1", Value="1"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Cidade 2", Value="2"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Cidade 3", Value="3"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Cidade 4", Value="4"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Cidade 5", Value="5"}
            };

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DropDown(SeuModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Faça o processamento desejado dos dados
                return View(model);
            }

            //Porém se a propriedade IsValid do ModelState não estiver válida você terá que retornar a View com os dados. 
            //Então, verá a mensagem de validação quando a tela for renderizada.
            ViewBag.Cidades = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Selecione", Value="", Selected = true},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Cidade 1", Value="1"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Cidade 2", Value="2"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Cidade 3", Value="3"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Cidade 4", Value="4"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Cidade 5", Value="5"}
            };

            return View(model);
        }
```

View:

```
@model SuaAplicacao.Models.SeuModel

<h2>Sua página</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CidadeID, "CidadeID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(e => e.CidadeID, ViewBag.Cidades as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Selecione")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.CidadeID)
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
}
```

**Exemplo com ViewModel:**

Model: Criei um ViewModel chamado SeuModel. É uma classe que será utilizada para obter os dados da tela, muito melhor do que trabalhar com ViewBags.

```
        public class SeuModel
        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe uma cidade")]
            [Display(Name = "Cidade")]
            public int CidadeID { get; set; } // Essa propriedade recebe o valor do item selecionado, se não vier valor a mensagem será exibida


            public List<SelectListItem> Cidades { get; set; } // Essa propriedade contém a lista dos itens

            public void PreencherListaCidades() // Esse método é para criar/recriar sua lista
            {
                Cidades = new List<SelectListItem>
                {
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Selecione", Value="", Selected = true},
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Cidade 1", Value="1"},
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Cidade 2", Value="2"},
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Cidade 3", Value="3"},
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Cidade 4", Value="4"},
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Cidade 5", Value="5"}
                };
            }        
        }
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult DropDown()
    {
        var model = new SeuModel();
        model.PreencherListaCidades();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DropDown(SeuModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Faça o processamento desejado dos dados
            return View(model);
        }

        //Porém se a propriedade IsValid do ModelState não estiver válida você terá que retornar a View com os dados. 
        //Então, verá a mensagem de validação quando a tela for renderizada.
        model.PreencherListaCidades();
        return View(model);
    }
```

View: Com a View do tipo do SeuModel você acessa as propriedades necessárias e renderiza os controles

```
@model SuaAplicacao.Models.SeuModel

<h2>Sua Página</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CidadeID, "CidadeID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CidadeID, Model.Cidades)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CidadeID)
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
}
```